# How to get package when Ubuntu Archive not working?

Tags: package-management

I'm trying to install Maven on my PC, but one of the packages it uses cannot. be installed from the package manager. Specifically libxmlgraphics-commons-java. I try going directly to the archive through my browser but no luck i.e. http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xmlgraphics-commons/

Comment: Use another mirror, see the above link for how to do that with software center.

Comment: What problems are you getting when you try and download the package, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the deb file right from the page you listed. I was just looking roght at them. Is your browser blocking the download for some reason? You can easily install it with Gdebi. If you dont't have Gdebi you can get it with ubuntu Software manager.